# How to erase ALL metadata associated with an image?

Tags: metadata, image-processing, geotagging, data-corruption, exiftool

I'm looking for a way to get rid of ALL metadata associated with an image. What should I do?

Comment: I consider the tags pools of thought that have something to offer.

Comment: Actually, that one is better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big-hammer approach is [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/)'s `-purejpg` option, which, according to the documentation:

> Deletes all JPEG sections that aren’t necessary for rendering the image. Strips any metadata that various applications  may  have left  in  the  image.

This is a cross-platform (Mac, Linux, Windows) command-line program. For example, if you want to remove metadata from a file named "image.jpg" in the current directory, you would run

```
jhead -purejpg image.jpg
```

and that is all there is to it.

Comment: Define "big-hammer", please. I vote for mattdm so far, namely because of your other accounts.

Comment: Hey, mattdm, how do I install this in the terminal?

Comment: @user3333975 Depends on your operating system. On Fedora, `sudo yum install jhead`. On Ubuntu or Debian, `sudo apt-get install jhead`. On Mac or Windows, you download them from the web site above and put them in your $PATH. If you don't know how to do that, this becomes a question for http://superuser.com/ :)

Comment: Big hammer: it's not very smart and doesn't give you any fine control,but it will definitely smash the metadata.

Comment: I see... Well, never mind about the terminal; I've got it.

Comment: How would I implement it? I mean, perhaps for people visiting this page who want a quick answer you could provide a command line example for an image in the current directory called image.jpg, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#tag_operations) is able to do this using the `-ALL=` (see the linked documentation). You can apply better control on this, however, and I would recommend that instead of just deleting all metadata. If you're looking to remove the location information, for example, just use some pattern matching.

Comment: Oh, no, I want all the data stripped, but yeah I get you with the regex that's easy enough to do if I just pipe it like this or something: exiftool img.jpg | tr 'MASTER PATTERN' '\.'

Answer (score 0):

I use jpegoptim for stripping metadata:
    jpegoptim --strip-all filename

You could also open the image with Gimp and save it without the metadata.